# Variable does not exist Id developer console error

Tags: apex, variable

```java
map<Account, list< contact>> AccountContact = new map<Account, list< contact>>();
  
accountRecs = [SELECT Id, Name, Active_Contacts__c,(SELECT Id from CONTACTS WHERE Active__c = TRUE)  FROM Account WHERE Active_Contacts__c > 0 AND Id!=NULL]; 
    
for(account acc :accountRecs){
    if(!AccountContact.containskey(acc)){
        if(acc.contacts.size() > 0){
            accountContact.get(acc).Id;
```

The fourth line from the for loop in my above code gives me Variable does not Exists Id. But I see Id is present in the Account object.

When I try with Name, then also, it is showing the same error. But these column names are present in the Account Object.

I am not sure if the above syntax is right. Can any one please help?

Comment: Hi Brindha,  I don't see any logic of adding the values to the map AccountContact. As the map is null this is causing issue I guess

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, But can you please help me with the correct syntax for the fourth line? It is saying Id does not exists.  I will check and correct the logic afterwards.

Answer (score 2):

This `accountContact` is a `Map<Account, List< contact>>`

So if you do `accountContact.get(acc).Id;` it will return you the `List<Contact>`. Which does not have direct Id, you need to loop in and get to Contact Id from that.

Note: Placing direct Account in key is not good approach. Replace that with AccountId instead.

Answer (score 2):

Your code, as written, has several issues with it, but let's focus on the error first.

#### Explaining the error

You're getting this error because you're trying to get an Id from a `List`.

You define `accountContact` as a `Map<Account, List<Contact>>`, so when `accountContact.get(acc)` is evaluated, you get a `List<Contact>`.

The offending line of code, partially evaluated, is `[an instance of List<Contact>].Id`. Your code is trying to access the `Id` class variable of the `List` type, and `List` has no class variables.

#### The issues with your code

Using SObjects as the key in a `Map` (or as the type specified for a `Set`) can be useful, but is not something I'd recommend for beginners. Making any change to the instance of an object used as a key for a Map causes you to lose the ability to retrieve some data from the map.

A `Map<Id, List<Contact>>` would be more appropriate.

Your query has a useless filter in it `Id != null`. Any record that can be queried will have an Id. No exceptions.

Your query is filtering accounts with more than 0 active contacts, so the `if(acc.contacts.size() > 0)` check is redundant

Accessing child records (or the embedded list of child records like you do with `acct.contacts.size()`) directly carries some risk with it. Once you have a certain amount of child records, Salesforce would need to perform an internal call to `queryMore()` and then throw an exception. The safe way to access child records here is to have a nested loop.

e.g.

```
for(Account acct :myAccounts){
    List<Contact> safeList = new List<Contact>();

    for(Contact cont :acct.Contacts){
        safeList.add(cont);
    }
}
```

It's hard to tell exactly what you're trying to do with `accountContact`, but given that you have `if(!accountContact.containsKey(...))` I assume you're trying to put data into the map.

The general pattern used to populate maps looks something like this:

```
Map<Id, List<ChildObject__c>> parentIdToChildren = new Map<Id, List<ChildObject__c>>();

for(Parent par :myParentList){
    // The general idea is to make sure that there will always be something in the map
    //   (that we can use) after this if() block
    // This tries to keep typing and repetition to a minimum, and allows us to skip
    //   the null checks that other approaches would need to do.
    if(!parentIdToChildren.containsKey(par.Id)){
        // By putting an empty list into the map (and not trying to immediately add
        //   the first record), the code to add the first record and the code to add
        //   all subsequent records becomes the same.
        // This allows us to avoid needing an ELSE block
        parentIdToChildren.put(par.Id, new List<ChildObject__c>());
    }

    for(ChildObject__c child :par.Children){
        // At this point, parentIdToChildren is guaranteed to have a non-null value
        //   stored for the map's key (the parent's Id)
        // Collections are stored in maps as references, so we can directly call .add()
        //   without needing to declare a temporary variable to hold the result of
        //   map.get(<key>)
        parentIdToChildren.get(par.Id).add(child);
    }
}
```